# Closing tabs with a specific meta TAG in firefox-addon using javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have this addon which inserts the following "meta" TAG on the pages it opens.Towards the end, I want to close all the tabs with that TAG on the page header.

```
<meta id="CLOSE_LATER">
```

I have written a simple for-loop:

```
var TAG = "CLOSE_LATER";
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

for(var i=0; i<tabs.length; i++){
    var tab = tabs[i];

        console.log("****START****");
        console.log("CLOSING TAB : "+i+"of : "+tabs.length);
    searchTag(tab, TAG,i)
    .then(function success(rValue) {
        if (rValue) {
            tab.close();
            console.log("CLOSED i: "+i);                
        }
        else{
            console.log("NOT CLOSED i: "+i);
        }
    }, function failure(error) {
        console.log("Error : searchTag()");
    });
    console.log("****END****");     
}
```

Where searchTag() attached a script to the page "seachtag.js" to search the TAG.

searchTag() returns a promise resolved to TRUE is it find the TAG on the page and resolves to FALSE otherwise.

Example situation: I have 3 URL's of which only URL-2 and URL-3 have the TAG in their head. So only URL-2 & 3 should be closed, but  only URL-3 is closed.

Below is the example log:

[image]

Comment: What I observe from the output is by the time searchTag() has returned TRUE/ FALSE the for loop continues and variable "tab" now hold the last tab and since searchTag() returns TRUE it is closed. How do I pause the loop from advancing to next until searachTag() returns a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var TAG = "CLOSE_LATER";
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

var success = function (rValue) {
    if (rValue) {
        this.close();
        //console.log("CLOSED i: "+i);                
    }
    else{
        //console.log("NOT CLOSED i: "+i);
    }
};

for(var i=0; i<tabs.length; i++){
    var tab = tabs[i];

        console.log("****START****");
        console.log("CLOSING TAB : "+i+"of : "+tabs.length);
    searchTag(tab, TAG,i)
    .then(success.bind(tab), function failure(error) {
        console.log("Error : searchTag()");
    });
    console.log("****END****");     
}
```

That binds the `tab` you are interested in to the `this` variable in the `success` function so that each invocation of `success` will have the correct `tab` object to work with.

Note that I commented out the logging because you no longer have access to `i` but if you want that to work again you'll just have to encapsulate `tab` and `i` in a new object for each loop iteration and bind that instead.

I've not used this trick inside a promise before so it's possible the promise resolution will do something to break the binding but hopefully not.